# How to select the previous/next node on the same level in a treeview after pressing certain keys?

Tags: c#

Let's say there's a treeview:

```
item1
|_item2
|  |_item3
|  |_item4
|_item5
|_item6
```

If the user presses CTRL Up or CTRL Down, how to make the cursor to stay on level 1, to navigate only between item2, item5, and item6?

I thought about the logic behind this operation:

```
if (user presses ctrl down) and (level is 1) and (the next node exists)
    go to the next node from level 1
```

How to implement that in C#? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you subscribe to the KeyDown event, you can just use the Index property of the current node.

This example only handles the Control-Down Arrow scenario:

```
void treeView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
  if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Down) {
    TreeNode tn = treeView1.SelectedNode;
    if (tn != null) {
      if (tn.Parent == null) {
        if (tn.Index < treeView1.Nodes.Count - 1) {
          treeView1.SelectedNode = treeView1.Nodes[tn.Index + 1];
        }
      } else {
        if (tn.Index < tn.Parent.Nodes.Count - 1) {
          treeView1.SelectedNode = tn.Parent.Nodes[tn.Index + 1];
        }
      }
    e.Handled = true;
    }
  }
}
```